# Count letters in a word

Tags: ruby, string

I want to count the small letter alphabets present in a string. Say I have:

```
a = "SaMarMiShrA"
```

I know that a.count("a-z") will give the answer. But how to do without using this without inbuilt methods.

Then,

```
def count_small_letters
  #code
end
a.count_small_letters
```

should return `6` since in `"SaMarMiShrA"`, the number of small letter alphabets is 6. Please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. I don't like homework questions. Can you show what you've tried so far, provide a non-working solution etc?

Comment: I tried doing like this a.each_byte do |c|
    puts c
end
yields

Comment: It will give the assci codes and the small letter ASCII are less than 65 or equal and tried counting them . it did not worked.

Comment: Why are you mentioning the counts in `"SaMarMiShrA"` when you are counting the relevant letters in `" SaMarMiShrA"`?

Comment: @Зелёный Y u down voted. If don't want to ans better keep away. I have tried my best den only asked .

Comment: @TopherHunt Its not like that. I was trying it myself and did not got working code thats y asked. If not want ans then don't and don't down vote it.

Comment: @SamarKrMishra I see it as my right (and responsibility) to upvote questions that I think are clear and helpful to others; and downvote questions that I think aren't. You asked a question that didn't show any effort at solving the problem, so I downvoted. I don't mean anything personal by it and I'd encourage you to keep asking more questions (and providing clearer examples of what you've tried!) in order to ask more useful questions in the future, but in my view "If don't want to ans better keep away" is not how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to be able to do "whatever".count_small_letters you would have to monkey patch String so

```
class String
  def count_small_letters
    #any of @Зелёный suggestions or
    scan(/[a-z]/).count
  end
end
```

Then:

```
> " SaMarMiShrA".count_small_letters
> 6
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-count):

```
=> "SaMarMiShrA".count("a-z")
#> 6
=> "SaMarMiShrA".count("A-Z")
#> 5
```

Other way:

```
=> "SaMarMiShrA".chars.find_all { |x| /[[:lower:]]/.match(x) }.count
#> 6
```

Comment: Use `count`, avoid the other way ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
def lower_case(string)
  count = 0
  string.split(//).each do |char|
    if char == char.downcase
      count += 1
    end
  end
  return count
end

puts lower_case("AAAaaa")

=> 3
```